# Log4j2 Stop/Close FileManager in Routing appender

Tags: logging, log4j2

Have the following log4j2 configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%T] %t %-5level %logger{36} - %msg}%n%throwable"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="FileAppender" fileName="${log4j:configParentLocation}/../test-output/logs/entire.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%T] %t %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%throwable"/>
    </File>
    <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
        <Routes pattern="$${ctx:logFilePath}">
            <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has a value for logFileName.
             The value dynamically determines the name of the log file. -->
            <Route>
                <File name="TestAppender" fileName="${ctx:logFilePath}" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%T] %t %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%throwable"/>
                </File>
            </Route>
             <!--This route is chosen if ThreadContext has no value for key logFileName.-->
            <Route key="$${ctx:logFilePath}">
                <File name="ConfigurationAppender" fileName="${log4j:configParentLocation}/../test-output/logs/configuration.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
                    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%T] %t %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%throwable"/>
                </File>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I am trying to delete RoutingAppender log file as soon as I don't need it anymore. However I cannot do it because got error that file is locked by logger FileManager.

Any idea how can I call Stop/Close FileManage for file in RoutingAppender?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used LogManager.getContext incorrectly.
I used LogManager.getContext(**true**). But should use LogManager.getContext(**false**). In case of **true** context doesn't see internal FileAppenders of RoutingAppender

```
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    RoutingAppender routingAppender = context.getConfiguration().getAppender("RoutingAppender");
    final FileAppender fileAppender = (FileAppender) routingAppender.getAppenders().get("MyAppender").getAppender();
    fileAppender.getManager().close();
```